# My Theme Is Lost

Tags: theming

My theme was working earlier, now when I go to the site, it just shows a basic homepage without the theme. I looked at the files and they are all there including the page.tpl.php file.

Not sure what would make that happen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you disable your theme? Try navigating to Appearance on the top Menu Bar, and see which theme is enabled, and if your theme is still recognized by Drupal.

It may be just a matter of reenabling it from that interface.

Comment: the theme is still on the server and shows up in appearance. I'm using Dreamweaver as my ftp and i think i stroked something to remove a part of the template. i'm not sure how to fix it, so I just recreated the theme and moved forward. Thanks for your help guys. BTW, I hate DreamWeaver.

Comment: I've heard Macaw is a really good (and modern) alternative to DreamWeaver--it doesn't produce nearly as much extra markup.

Answer (score 0):

Is your theme still presents in the /sites/all/themes path ?
If yes, i guess he's disable in your apparence administration.